# Repeat footer background image horizontally to fill browser window

Tags: footer

I'm racking my brain trying to figure this one out. I thought it was going to be easy : ) I simply want the Footer to extend the width of my browser window while the Footer Wrap contains the content within 960px, but for some reason it only fills to the 960px. Here's my code:

```
footer {
background: url(images/footerbkg.jpg) repeat-x bottom center;
width: 100%;
height: 1232px;
```

}

```
footer section.wrap {
width: 960px;
margin: 60px auto 0;
position: relative;
float: left;
```

}

Comment: is `footer` in another overall container that's got a width set? It would help if you could you set up an example of the problem as a fiddle.

Comment: Hello, yes it's inside the wrapper: `#wrapper {
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}`

Comment: In that case you need to put it below the wrapper ;)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it. I'll answer it "officially" for the sake of the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites' footers are contained within an overall wrapper. Make sure you've placed the footer div (or footer tag if you're using HTML5) outside of the wrapper. 100% width should fill the screen if it is.